# Java: SQL Query: rs.next() is false after updating a column

Tags: java, sql

I have a strange problem. I have a database and I want to change the values of a column. The values are safed in an Arraylist (timelist).

In order to write the values in the right row, I have a second Arrylist (namelist). So I want to read the first row in my Database, than I check the namelist and find the name. Than i take the matching value out of the timelist and write it into the database into the column "follows_date" in the row, matching to the name.

And than I read the next row of the Database, until there are no more entries.

So the strange thing is, if I change nothing in the database, the `while(rs.next())` part works.

For example:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT username FROM users");
      while(rs.next()){

          // read the result set
          String name = rs.getString("username");
          System.out.println("username = " + name); //liest die namen
          }
      }
```

This would print me every name after name. But when I change the table, the while loop ends after that. (no error, the program just finishes)

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT username FROM users");
      while(rs.next()){

          // read the result set
          String name = rs.getString("username");
          System.out.println("username = " + name); //writes the name

        //look, if name is in Arraylist "namelist"). if yes, than write the matching date from "timelist" into the database.
          if (namelist.contains(name)){
              System.out.println("name found: "+ name);
              int listIndizi = namelist.indexOf(name); //get index
              Long indiziDatum = (long) timelist.get(listIndizi); //get date from same Index
              System.out.println(indiziDatum); // print date so i can see it is correct (which it is)

              statement.executeUpdate("UPDATE users SET follows_date ="+ indiziDatum +" WHERE username = '"+name+"'"); //updates the follows_date column

          }
      }
```

Everything works fine, except that now, the while loop doesn't continues after the first passage, but ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resultSet of a statement is closed and will not return further results if you execute another statement. Create a new separate statement object for the update  and everything should work as excepted.

```
Statement statement1 = connection.createStatement();
Statement statement2 = connection.createStatement();

ResultSet resultSet1 = statement1.executeQuery("SELECT username FROM users");
while(resultSet1.next()){
...
    statement2.executeUpdate("UPDATE users ..."));
}
```

Comment: aha very interersting, i didn't know that. I will try this. thanks :)

Comment: yes it works now. Is it possible, to declare 2 statemants to seperate variables, at the same time?

Comment: I don't undestand the question? You can have as many statement objects as you like. Can you post the (pseudo) code in question ? And don't forget to accept the answer :-)

Comment: I put this, befor the end, of the while loop. But this takes forever....

rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT username FROM users WHERE follows_date IS NULL");

So i want to do something like this: rs2 = statement.executeUpdate(...) to update the row, while not loosing rs1

Comment: Pseudocode:
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.setQueryTimeout(30);

Statement statement2 = connection.createStatement();

Comment: @aragonthebest I edited my answer to give an example. You will not lose resultSet1 and can still execute statement2. executeUpdate() doesn't return a result set, but the number or changed rows.

Answer (score 0):

As to ***Why*** it happens:

Here is the explanation from the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

***Alternative Approach:***

From your sample, it seems you are trying to update the "same" row in your resultSet, you should consider using an Updatable ResultSet.

Sample code from the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html#rs_update):

```
public void modifyPrices(float percentage) throws SQLException {

    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                   ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet uprs = stmt.executeQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM " + dbName + ".COFFEES");

        while (uprs.next()) {
            float f = uprs.getFloat("PRICE");
            uprs.updateFloat( "PRICE", f * percentage);
            uprs.updateRow();
        }

    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
    }
}
```